# How to use Multiple React-Bootstrap modals?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5, react-bootstrap, react-typescript, react-bootstrap4-modal

I have a react bootstrap modal where I am mapping my data but the problem is when I click on modals, all the modals display same data, its apparently the last item of the array in all modals. I want to generate modal dynamically and show different data for different modal.

```
const content: { cardimg: string, Name: string, Post: string, Nation: string, About: string, mod:string }[] = [
{
"cardimg": `hello`,
"Name": "someone 1",
"Post": "Chairman & CEO",
"Nation": "India",
"About": "holds a degree of Executive MBA in Entrepreneurship from Rennes School of Business, France.",
"mod": "one"
},
{
"cardimg": `world`,
"Name": "someone 2",
"Post": "Deputy CEO",
"Nation": "India",
"About": "holds a degree in MBA Finance, someone 2 has more than 7 years of experience in Customer Engagement Services.",
"mod": "two"
},

const Leadershipcard = (prop: props) =\> {

    const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false)
    
    
    return (
        <>
            {content.map((e) =>
                <div className="card col-lg-6 p-0" style={{ "width": "18rem" } as React.CSSProperties}>
                    <img src={`Assets\\About\\team\\${e.cardimg}.webp`} className="card-img-top" alt="..." />
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <h5 className="card-title">{e.Name}</h5>
                        <p className="card-text">{e.Post}</p>
                        <a href="/" className="d-block fs-4"><i className="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
                        <button className="btn btn-outline-dark btn-dark rounded-0 text-bg-light mt-2 vi-more"
                            onClick={() => setModalShow(true)} data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target={`/mod${e.mod}`}>View More</button>
                       ** <Modals
                            show={modalShow}
                            onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
                            Img={e.cardimg}
                            Name={e.Name}
                            Post={e.Post}
                            Nation={e.Nation}
                            About={e.About}
                            mod={e.mod}
                        />**
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </>
    )

}

export default Leadershipcard
```

```
[Modal component that I used (Bold text above)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg01P.png)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modal states have to be maintained in an array to keep track of specific modals.

We can achieve it by passing index of array when opening and closing the modal.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Modal } from "react-bootstrap";

const Modals = ({ show, onHide, about, name }) => {
  return (
    <Modal show={show} onHide={onHide}>
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title>{name}</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>{about}</Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="secondary" onClick={onHide}>
          Close
        </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
};

const content = [
  {
    cardimg: `hello`,
    Name: "someone 1",
    Post: "Chairman & CEO",
    Nation: "India",
    About:
      "Holds a degree of Executive MBA in Entrepreneurship from Rennes School of Business, France.",
    mod: "one"
  },
  {
    cardimg: `world`,
    Name: "someone 2",
    Post: "Deputy CEO",
    Nation: "India",
    About:
      "Holds a degree in MBA Finance, someone 2 has more than 7 years of experience in Customer Engagement Services.",
    mod: "two"
  }
];

const LeadershipCard = (prop) => {
  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState([]);

  const handShow = (index) => {
    const modalStateClone = [...modalShow];
    modalStateClone[index] = true;
    setModalShow(modalStateClone);
  };

  const handleClose = (index) => {
    const modalStateClone = [...modalShow];
    modalStateClone[index] = false;
    setModalShow(modalStateClone);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (content?.length > 0) {
      const contentArr = content.map((c) => {
        return false;
      });
      console.log(contentArr);
      setModalShow(contentArr);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {content.map((e, index) => (
        <div
          className="card col-lg-6 p-0"
          style={{ width: "18rem" }}
          key={index}
        >
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{e.Name}</h5>
            <p className="card-text">{e.Post}</p>
            <a href="/" className="d-block fs-4">
              <i className="fa-brands fa-linkedin-in"></i>
            </a>
            <button
              className="btn btn-outline-dark btn-dark rounded-0 text-bg-light mt-2 vi-more"
              onClick={() => handShow(index)}
              data-bs-toggle="modal"
              data-bs-target={`/mod${e.mod}`}
            >
              View More
            </button>
            <Modals
              key={index}
              show={modalShow[index]}
              onHide={() => handleClose(index)}
              img={e.cardimg}
              name={e.Name}
              post={e.Post}
              nation={e.Nation}
              about={e.About}
              mod={e.mod}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default LeadershipCard;
```

I have created CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-pond-f6972v?file=/src/LeaderShip.js:0-2747) for live demo.